# run kubernetes job in cloud builder

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to create and remove a job using Google Cloud Builder. Here's my configuration which builds my Docker image and pushes to GCR.

```
# cloudbuild.yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/xyz/abc:latest','-f','Dockerfile.ng-unit','.']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/xyz/abc:latest']
```

Now I want to create a job , I want to run something like

`kubectl create -R -f ./kubernetes`

which creates job in kubernetes folder.

I know cloud builder has `- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'` but I can't figure out how to use it. Plus how can I authenticate it to run kubectl commands? How can I use service_key.json

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to connect and get cluster credentials. Here's what I did

> Go to IAM, add another Role to xyz@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com. I used Project Editor.
>
> Wrote this on cloudbuild.yaml `name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
>     args: ['create', '-R', '-f','./dockertests/unit-tests/kubernetes']`